# React Native: how to use require(path) with dynamic urls?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, require

I want to use WebView to show some html content

here is an example:

```
return (
            <WebView
                    style={styles.container}
                    source={source}
                    scalesPageToFit={Boolean(true)}
                    onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange} />
    )
```

and for the **source** variable I need to have two different values:

1) for android platform I need to use something like this:

```
source = {uri: `file:///android_asset/contents/${languageId}text.html`}
```

2) for ios I need to use smth. like this:

```
source = require(`../srv/localization/contents/${languageId}text.html`)
```

For android it works well, but for ios it doesn't work.
And this url works fine for iOS also

```
require(`../srv/localization/contents/entext.html`)
```

As I understand that is because of dynamic url (${languageId}text.html)

The question is how to use dynamic urls for iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you find out, you can't have dynamic *url* for *require*. That's because *require* get the source at the app start regardless it's place  in the code. You shuld require all of the *{languageId}text.html* and pass the required variable to the source:

```js
var language = {
   en: require(`../srv/localization/contents/entext.html`)
   ...
}
```

and use it as below:

```
source = require(language[en])
```

Comment: @Dmitry, i edited the answer for using with *var*. t

Comment: But what if I don't want to require all files. In one case I need to require entext.html, but in other case I need to require pttext.html. I don't want to store all the files that will probably required in the future. I want to add all necessary files before making a build and require them by prefix in the code  @Meysam Izadmehr

Comment: If your user can change the language in he app, there is not other way with *require*. If the user can't change the language and text.html is not a small file, make a build for each language. If you don't want to *require* all the files, maybe you shouldn't use it in the first place. for example you can fetching it from server when user want to change language.